# Confused about Alamofire sessionmanager

Tags: swift3, alamofire, afhttpsessionmanager

Using Alamofire 4.0 and Swift 3.0 this works:

```
Alamofire.request("http://content.uplynk.com/player/assetinfo/ab19f0dc98dc4b7dbfcf88fa223a6c3b.json", method: .get).responseJSON {
(response) -> Void in
print("Success: \(response.result)")
}
```

> Success: SUCCESS

However when I try to use the Sessionmanager so I can include a timeoutInterval, my requests always fail

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15
let alamofireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)   
alamofireManager.request("http://content.uplynk.com/player/assetinfo/ab19f0dc98dc4b7dbfcf88fa223a6c3b.json").validate().responseJSON { 
    response in
    print("Success: \(response.result)")
    print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
}
```

> Success: FAILURE

Would be grateful if someone could help point me in the right direction here.

Answer (score 15):

By printing `response.result.error` I got:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://content.uplynk.com/player/assetinfo/ab19f0dc98dc4b7dbfcf88fa223a6c3b.json, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://content.uplynk.com/player/assetinfo/ab19f0dc98dc4b7dbfcf88fa223a6c3b.json}
```

Which lead me to this [reference](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/157):

> You need to make sure that the manager is retained. The difference
>   here is that the initialized manager is not owned, and is deallocated
>   shortly after it goes out of scope. As a result, any pending tasks are
>   cancelled.

**Solution:**

One way to solve the issue your having is by declaring the custom session manager outside of the class declaration as a global variable like so...

```
let sessionManager: SessionManager = {
  let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
  configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15

  return SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
}()
```

Now, within your class you can make the request.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  let url = "http://content.uplynk.com/player/assetinfo/ab19f0dc98dc4b7dbfcf88fa223a6c3b.json"

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sessionManager.request(url).validate().responseJSON { response in
      switch response.result {
        case .success:
          print(response.result.value as! NSDictionary)
          break

        case .failure:
          print(response.result.error!)
          break
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Which shall give you what you're looking for. Hope that helps!

Comment: very very helpful and this absolutely solves my issue.  thanks very much for taking the time to reply with such a thorough answer and example!